How do I convert an id that defaults to comma-separated string to an array of strings?
I am trying to pass data from Formidable Forms to Brevo with an API. Here is my code so far:
{ "updateEnabled": true,
    "email": "[376]",
    "emailBlacklisted": false, 
    "smsBlacklisted": false,
    "attributes": {
        "FIRSTNAME": "[374]",  
        "LASTNAME": "[375]",   
        "GENRE": ["[385]"]
         
    },
    "listIds": [2]   
}

It works perfectly until I add in genres. The id 385 is the answers for a multiple-selection question in Formidable Forms and has the same answers as the GENRE attribute in Brevo. Formidable Forms defaults to a comma separated format but Brevo requires an array of strings. Currently, it will pass the data only if the first option in the form is selected. If anything else is selected, the other data transfers but the genre is left blank. Any ideas on how I can get it to pass all of the genre data in an array?
I tried the code listed above and I also tried the below (adding .split to help make it an array).
let selectedGenres = formData[385]; 
let genreArray = selectedGenres.split(',').map(item => item.trim());

let apiRequest = {
  "updateEnabled": true,
  "email": "[376]",
  "emailBlacklisted": false,
  "smsBlacklisted": false,
  "attributes": {
    "FIRSTNAME": "[374]",
    "LASTNAME": "[375]",
    "GENRE": genreArray 
  },
  "listIds": [2]
};


What is the "code listed above"? I only see one block of code.

Please show sample values of selectedGenres. We're just guessing what problem you're having.

i'd suggest using string.match(regex_pattern) like below:
var my_id_string = 'example1,example2,example3'
var my_regex = /(?:,|\n|^)("(?:(?:"")*[^"]*)*"|[^",\n]*|(?:\n|$))/g
var matches = my_id_string.match(my_regex);

the regex is a bit nutty, but it should handle 'normal' csv and odd cases like double quotes, double commas, starting with a comma and more

How does this solve the problem of generating the result in the proper format?

Where did you get the idea that the problem is with quotes?

comma-seperated string to array of strings... that's what the code does. it generates an array of strings, whats not proper about it?  i didn't think the problem was with quotes, but since I don't have a set of example data I have to assume you may or may not have properly formatted data to work on and so the code handles those situations.  maybe i misunderstood the problem but according to the title there's nothing wrong with this answer.  saying "here's my code" and supplying a JSON object doesn't give much to go off of to try and guess your intentions

Look at their desired result, it's supposed to have [] around the ID, as in "[385]"

"[385],[386],[387]" turns into ["[385]","[386]","[387]"], how is that not right?  like i said, it takes CSV and turns it into an array of strings.  it grabs anything between commas.

I'm assuming the input is just 385,386,387 without the [], and they need to be added. Otherwise the OP's code would work.

What problem do you think you're solving in the OP's code? It looks like you're just removing quotes from the input before splitting.

and how should I know the input is 385, 386, 387?  you're assuming just like i was.  also, only known thing here is that input is some sort of string with commas so even if it is "385,386,387" as input you end up with ["385","386","387"] and since it was never stated if brackets needed to be added or not this is still a valid answer... you already supplied a solution using split, what's wrong with an alternative?

If the form data doesn't already have [] around each ID, you need to add it.
let genreArray = selectedGenres.split(',').map(item => '[' + item.trim() + ']');

